# Could not load file or assembly Bond.IO

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

Using Microsoft.Bing.Speech nuget package and Net Framework 4.6.1
I'm having this exception when calling RecognizeAsync()

> Could not load file or assembly 'Bond.IO, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

My code:

```
public static async Task SpeechToTextStreamPO(Stream audioStream, string textResult)
    {
        var subscriptionKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BingSpeechSubscriptionKey"];

        Uri ShortPhraseUrl = new Uri(@"wss://speech.platform.bing.com/api/service/recognition");
        Uri LongDictationUrl = new Uri(@"wss://speech.platform.bing.com/api/service/recognition/continuous");
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        var preferences = new Microsoft.Bing.Speech.Preferences("en-IN", ShortPhraseUrl, new CognitiveServicesAuthorizationProvider(subscriptionKey));

        // Create a a speech client
        using (var speechClient = new SpeechClient(preferences))
        {
            speechClient.SubscribeToRecognitionResult(async (recognitionResult) =>
            {
                if (recognitionResult.RecognitionStatus == Microsoft.Bing.Speech.RecognitionStatus.Success)
                {
                    textResult = recognitionResult.Phrases[0].DisplayText;
                }
            });

            var deviceMetadata = new DeviceMetadata(DeviceType.Near, DeviceFamily.Mobile, NetworkType.CellLTE, OsName.Android, "1607", "Dell", "T3600");
            var applicationMetadata = new ApplicationMetadata("SampleApp", "1.0.0");
            var requestMetadata = new RequestMetadata(Guid.NewGuid(), deviceMetadata, applicationMetadata, "SampleAppService");

            await speechClient.RecognizeAsync(new SpeechInput(audioStream, requestMetadata), cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);}
    }
```

I've tried installing different versions and changing version numbers in .csproj but I can't make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: `tried installing different versions and changing version numbers in .csproj ` What's the version you have tested?

Comment: Microsoft.Bing.Speech 2.0.1 and 2.0.2
Tried also Bond 7.0.1. and 8.0.0

Comment: any luck ? i'm running into the exact same issue

could it be because we both are trying to mark a web-service function as async ?

Comment: No luck, I ended up removing the library and making a WebRequest manually.

Comment: @Imartin how did you do this manually with a web request, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Here goes the paste https://pastebin.com/fv0E6HUt @Digitalsa1nt

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me with changing Bond.Core.CSharp package to 4.2.0

Comment: very weird. this NuGet rollback works. Can the PG of Microsoft.Bing.Speech nuget package have a check? I can repro when Bond.Core.CSharp update to the latest.